# Batch file not executing in server

Tags: batch-file

I have been running a batch file to copy files from one location (my local machine) to multiple servers. Recently we moved into a server for processing files, now the problem is the same batch file is not working when I copy it from one server to another 2 or more servers....

Do I have to change any statements in the batch file pertaining to servers...?

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
echo copying files to multiple servers

copy *.eps* \\server1\adman\in\displ
copy *.eps* \\server2\BasketsIn\TheHindu\AdImport\Ads_SAP))
```

Comment: And, how does it not work? Is there any error?

Comment: It's not working at all... usually I will place the batch file into folder(C:\Users\bg****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo)... so that I can right click the file which I want to copy and navigate to sendto and select the batch file(which transmits the file into the path I mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

This will copy a static filemask of files from one server to two other servers.

You need read/write permissions over the lan.

```
@echo off
echo copying files to multiple servers
set "source_server=\\server0\c\share"

copy "%source_server%\*.eps*" "\\server1\adman\in\displ"
copy "%source_server%\*.eps*" "\\server2\BasketsIn\TheHindu\AdImport\Ads_SAP"
```

Comment: Sorry friend,

it's not working after applying the above commands too.. I have all the read/write permissions for all the servers..

Comment: It should at least have printed 'copying files to multiple servers' to the console window and then shown an error saying 'file not found' if there were no files to copy.  If you clicked on the batch file then try launching it after opening a command prompt. If your batch files aren't executing any commands then you need to reinstall Windows.